# Read lines from Text file

Tags: java, file-io

I just want to read some specific lines from a text file not all the lines.
I tried the following code:

```
public class BufferedReaderDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        FileReader fr = new FileReader("Demo.txt");
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(fr);
        String line = br.readLine();

        while(line!=null)
        {
            System.out.println(line);
            line = br.readLine();
        }

        br.close();
    }
}
```

Using this code I am able to get all the lines. But I want to print some specific 2–3 lines in console that start with "namespace" and end with "Console".

How can I achieve this?

Comment: *"How can I achieve this?"* By using an `if` statement.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask It might also help if you showed the data you are reading

Answer (score 1):

You have no choice, if you want to know if a line contains some specific words, you have to read it.

If you want only print these lines, you can add a condition before printing them.

```
String line = br.readLine();

while(line!=null){
    if (line.startsWith("namespace") && line.endsWith("Console")){
       System.out.println(line);
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.startsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#startsWith-java.lang.String-) and [`String.endsWith`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#endsWith-java.lang.String-):

```
while(line!=null)
{
    if(line.startsWith("namespace") && line.endsWith("Console")) {
        System.out.println(line);
    }
    line = br.readLine();
}
```